# How to pass id from ui_component to model?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin-panel, adminform

I have a form, see image below.

[image]

I have the following data in the database, see image below

[image]

I originally wanted to have the structure like below in the custom table

```
> id | meta_key   |  meta_value
> ------------------------------- 
> 1  | first_name |  Absolute
> ------------------------------
> 2  | last_name  |  Idiot
```

But I don't know how to do this with ui_component (update, retrieve data)? (if someone knows how to do this. please provide some info)

So I resorted to what I know of

My current problem, when I load the form, I don't want to pass id/1 in my URL **instead, I want the data from id 1 to be loaded by default.**

Assuming the only needed codes are ui_component_form and data provider I have provided them below.

> DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Absolute\Idiot\Model\Sample1;
use Absolute\Idiot\Model\ResourceModel\Sample1\CollectionFactory;
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $contactCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $contactCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        $this->loadedData = array();
        foreach ($items as $user) {
            $this->loadedData[$user->getId()]['sample1'] = $user->getData();
        }

        return $this->loadedData;

    }
}
```

> idiot_sample1_form.xml (ui_component)

```
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">idiot_sample1_form.sample1_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">idiot_sample1_form.sample1_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
      <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample1</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">idiot_sample1_form</item>
        </item>

      <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save Sample Data</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/saveAction</item>
            </item>
        </item>

    </argument>


    <dataSource name="sample1_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Absolute\Idiot\Model\Sample1\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sample1_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">sample_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="sample1_details">

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample1 Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="sample_id" formElement="input" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/input</elementTmpl>
                <label translate="true">Sample Id</label>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="first_name" formElement="input" sortOrder="20">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/input</elementTmpl>
                <label translate="true">First Name</label>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="last_name" formElement="input" sortOrder="30">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/input</elementTmpl>
                <label translate="true">Last Name</label>
            </settings>
        </field>



    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your listing.xml uicompnent file set actionsColumn node to set URL of edit and delete.

here my `view/adminhtml/ui_component/sample_listing.xml`

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PR\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
```

set correct class and ID in this file `class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PR\Actions"` and `indexField` ID

> ```
> Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PR\Actions
> ```

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PR;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Actions extends Column
{

    const URL_PATH_EDIT = 'pbvreview/productreview/edit';
    const URL_PATH_DELETE = 'pbvreview/productreview/delete';

    protected $actionUrlBuilder;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    private $editUrl;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::URL_PATH_EDIT
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        $this->editUrl = $editUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->editUrl, ['id' => $item['id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(self::URL_PATH_DELETE, ['id' => $item['id']]),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.title }'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.title } record?')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answer. I am relatively new to magento. But can i pass the id directly from the form via xml directly to the dataprovider. I don't want to list the data in grid or table.

Comment: try to implement Ui Component step by step so you can learn properly

Comment: use full links https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-form.html

Comment: http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-create-uicomponent-list-and-uicomponent-form-by-example

Comment: Thanks for the links. Sorry if i am wrong, After checking your code i think what you have provided is the code for grid view/ Table. I don't want table view with action  columns like edit/delete. when i click the admin menu of my custom extension, a form is provided, Please look at second structure of database i have provided in the original question. Maybe u will understand what i meant. Its like a configuration form for an extension so i don't need grid view.

Comment: How will you decide to which id  update you?